# I am trying to create a script that will change css class on SVG on when mouse is over a link

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a SVG of a world map with 7 region section and above the world map is row of 7 region names that link to each of the region page.

The world map is a inline SVG and regions are grouped by ID and classes but all region is set to grey class and I trying use fill class on SVG when a mouse is over a region link to show the viewer which parts of the world that region covers.

Can anyone help me write a script for this?

Thank you

Comment: I been researching and searching for some time. All I found is how to fill when a mouse is over SVG itself which is not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is how to fill when a mouse is over a text that is not part of a SVG . A list of text on above the SVG and each text is linked to an ID inside the SVG

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the below code should work, with 7 of these lines of code - one for each section. Section1Name being the Id of the link, mapSvgSection the Id of the relevant section of the Svg. The first colour is on mouse enter, and the second is on mouse leave. Below is blue on enter and grey on leave, they would be changed to whatever you require
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$("#section1Name").hover( $("#mapSvgSection").css({ fill: "#0000FF" }), $("#mapSvgSection").css({ fill: "#707070" }));
```

Comment: Yes I found something very similar to your line of code yesterday and got it working. I will save your code in my note for future reference too.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please could you accept my answer if it's helpful/works? Thanks!